# Invalid form submission in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have a wordpress based classifieds site, i am trying to create and xml feed application that fetches xml from other sites and create ads. I am able to create post in wordpress from the feeds. But i cant copy the images from the remote server,there are no permission issues, i am using the worpress function wp_handle_upload_error, But i get error

This the code

```
   public function xml_image_upload($upload)
    {
        if ($this->xml_file_is_image($upload['tmp_name'])) 
            {
                $file = wp_handle_upload($upload, $overrides);
            }
    return $file;
    }
```

The error i get is "**Invalid form submission**"

I am trying to solve this for a long time. I cant figure out whats wrong..

Comment: Does the feeds actually send the images?

Comment: The feeds have the url to the image, we pick the images with the url and upload it using wp_handle_upload (which is not working)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to pass `array('test_form' => FALSE)` as the second parameter or the upload will be rejected for some reason.
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload#Parameters

Comment: "you have to pass some random array for this function to work" Gosh wordpress bugs me, but thanks for the solution!

Comment: As with any evolving API, awkward stuff needs to be left behind for some historical reason and backwards compatibility, but they do a good cleanup now and then

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder why they made it so you have to do this O_O

Comment: tried to set it the same as my form's action parameter as the codex suggests, but doesn't work. This "overcoming security" does. Idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of `wp_handle_upload` is important.

Use `array('action' => 'name_of_your_action')` (without prefix `admin_post_` or `wp_ajax_`).