# Using PHP for file-upload in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files from the front end of a wordpress page to send to the back-end wordpress directory within wp-content. I can't figure out why files are not appearing in the back end folder 'uploads' which is what the $target_dir is set as. Here is my **HTML** form on one page.

```
<form action="http://www.aeroex.co.uk/php-upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

The form action page for the above form, www.aeroex.co.uk/php-upload/ , contains the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "http://www.aeroex.co.uk/home3/dy/public_html/wp-content/uploads";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pathinfo() expects a path not a URL.

$target_dir should be a path, eg: /home3/dy/public_html/wp-content/uploads. Check $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] if you are not sure.

```
$target_file = $target_dir . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Then, you've got a path where you want the files to be uploaded to.
Now you need to run:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Comment: Where do I run that line of code? Do I put it after $target_file ?

Comment: move_uploaded_file() is something you run if $uploadOk == 1. But before that please make sure you know what the $target_dir actually is. If I understand correctly, this should be its path: $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/uploads';

Comment: Although this works fine and is uploading my file to the directory, I keep getting the following message: Warning: getimagesize(/tmp/phpD8fHDn): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/ddy/public_html/wp-content/themes/vantage/templates/template-upload.php on line 26
File is not an image.

Comment: If you've already used move_uploaded_file() then the file will no longer be in this location: $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]. You want to use getimagesize() before you move it.

Lastly, I recommend consider Kalimah's answer too. It may not always be applicable but is the recommended Wordpress way of handling uploads.

Comment: It was sorted by changing $check = getimagesize($target_file); . The message no longer comes up so its all working fine.

Answer (score 14):

A recommended approach is to use **[wp_handle_upload()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/)** function. You can use it with  **[wp_insert_attachment()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/)** if you wanted to add files to media library.

The first function wp_handle_upload() does:

> Handle PHP uploads in WordPress, sanitizing file names, **checking
> extensions for mime type**, and **moving the file to the appropriate
> directory within the uploads directory**.

An example from WordPress site with some changes

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
}

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];

/* You can use wp_check_filetype() function to check the
 file type and go on wit the upload or stop it.*/

$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile);

if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    /**
     * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
     * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
     */
    echo $movefile['error'];
}
```

Alternatively you could just use [wp_upload_dir()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) to get only the upload dir.

For more information on using native WordPress function for upload check this article:
**[How to Upload a File With WordPress’ Secret Native Functions](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/upload-file-functions/)**

Comment: Works to me only when I change the line to  `$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, array( 'test_form' => false ));` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019761/invalid-form-submission-in-wordpress)

Comment: Also i don't think how I would run wp_check_filetype() on $_FILES. An alternative I found working is `if (in_array(finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $uploadedfile['tmp_name']), array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif'))){ /*do the rest*/ }`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to upload a file to the library and attach it to a post you can use the Wordpress function [media_handle_upload()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/)

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'your_file_field_name', $post_id);
```

[See example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#user-contributed-notes)